# I get frequently SQLiteDoneException when querying one value, why?

Tags: android, exception, sqlite

I get frequently SQLiteDoneException,

```
06-29 02:03:34.816: WARN/System.err(30470): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDoneException: not an error
06-29 02:03:34.816: WARN/System.err(30470):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.native_1x1_string(Native Method)
06-29 02:03:34.816: WARN/System.err(30470):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.simpleQueryForString(SQLiteStatement.java:154)
06-29 02:03:34.826: WARN/System.err(30470):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(DatabaseUtils.java:669)
06-29 02:03:34.826: WARN/System.err(30470):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.stringForQuery(DatabaseUtils.java:652)
```

I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDoneException.html):

> An exception that indicates that the
>   SQLite program is done. Thrown when an
>   operation that expects a row (such as
>   simpleQueryForString() or
>   simpleQueryForLong()) does not get
>   one.

I don't think is very important, but it's a warning.

Answer (score 3):

From SQLiteStatement simpleQueryForLong code:

```
@throws android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDoneException if the query returns zero rows
```